# Recursive file list of all files, list containing path+name, type, size, creation data, modification date

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

Have looked around on stackoverflow, googled ... but nothing fits my requirement... :-) What I want/need is a flat txt file containing info on files in a certain dir and subdirs. There are ways to do this with 3rd party programs and from terminal/unix. Both ways would be fine by me. BUT ... I need all of the following info on the file:

Path and filename
Type (we are talking macintosh here, so it might come from the resource fork, many very old files, back to mid 90's!)

Filesize

Creation date

Modification date (this is not essential to have, just good to have).

Any good ideas? As mentioned, it could be a one-liner for the terminal that writes to a file or suggestion for a small app that can do it.

Thanks in advance :-)

EDIT: the output format doesn't matter much, can be tab or semicolon seperated or whatever, as long as it's a textfile - I can always modify it after. The important thing is the information is there... :-)

RESULT - what I ended up using (thanks for the help) :-)

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name '*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    name=$(basename "$file")
    path=$(dirname "$file")
    # full_path=$(readlink -f "$file") # This only works on Linux
    full_path=$(echo "$PWD/${file#./}")
    extension=${name##*.}
    size_human_readable=$(ls -lh "$file" | awk -F' ' '{print $5}')
    size_in_bytes=$(stat -f "%z" "$file")
    creation_date=$(stat -f "%SB" "$file")
    last_access=$(stat -f "%Sa" "$file")
    last_modification=$(stat -f "%Sm" "$file")
    last_change=$(stat -f "%Sc" "$file")
    creator=$(mdls -name kMDItemFSCreatorCode "$file")


    printf "\"%q\";" "$name"
    printf "\"%q\";" "$full_path"
    printf "%s" "\"$extension\";"
    printf "\"$size_human_readable\";"
    printf "\"$size_in_bytes\";"
    printf "\"$last_modification\";"
    printf "%s" "\"$creator\""
    printf "\n"
done
```

Comment: can you make a sample dir and show the generated output?

Comment: ...something like [this](https://gist.github.com/mamiu/095a161944b09b733701).

Comment: sure, it can be a dir with several / many dirs under it, hence recursive. The files can be anything, also (a lot of) files with no ending (i.e. old MAC files) ... for these it is important that I get the Type/creator from the Resource fork... :-)

Comment: what I want to know is, how should the "flat txt file" look like. Add it to your question ;-) Thx!

Comment: So gummiflummi .... :-) I updated my question as you asked me to do :-) Do you have a suggestion? :-)

Comment: aaanyone? anyone at all? No? :-)

Comment: Is the creation date even stored? It isn't on typical Unix-like systems; I'm less familiar with Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name '*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    name=$(basename "$file")
    path=$(dirname "$file")
    # full_path=$(readlink -f "$file") # This only works on Linux
    full_path=$(echo "$PWD/${file#./}")
    extension=${name##*.}
    size_human_readable=$(ls -lh "$file" | awk -F' ' '{print $5}')
    size_in_bytes=$(stat -f "%z" "$file")
    creation_date=$(stat -f "%SB" "$file")
    last_access=$(stat -f "%Sa" "$file")
    last_modification=$(stat -f "%Sm" "$file")
    last_change=$(stat -f "%Sc" "$file")

    printf "[$file]:\n"
    printf "\tfile name:\t\t$name\n"
    printf "\tfile path:\t\t$path\n"
    printf "\tfull file path:\t\t$full_path\n"
    printf "\tfile extension:\t\t$extension\n"
    printf "\tfile size:\t\t$size_human_readable\n"
    printf "\tfile size in bytes:\t$size_in_bytes\n"
    printf "\tfile creation date:\t$creation_date\n"
    printf "\tlast file access:\t$last_access\n"
    printf "\tlast file modification:\t$last_modification\n"
    printf "\tlast file change:\t$last_change\n"
    printf "\n"
done
```

Of course you can modify the output! Copy this script into a file (e.g. `recursive_file_info.sh`). Then make it executable with `chmod +x recursive_file_info.sh`. If you want the output in a text file you can redirect it with `./recursive_file_info.sh > files.txt`.

Comment: Thanks gummiflummi ... far from an unix expert ... have done as you instructed but are getting an error after executing it in the dir ir recides in (and where it should look for the files): -bash: ./recursive_file_info.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: I think you copied it to an editor which saved the file with windows line endings.
Open the Terminal on your Mac. Navigate to the directory you want to save your script. (If you are not familiar with the basic commands like `ls` and `cd`, I highly recommend to take a look at [this article](http://goo.gl/R1FcIv) or watch the screencast there)!
If you are in the right dir enter `cat << 'EOF' > recursive_file_info.sh` and then copy the script from the browser into the terminal. Hit **Enter**, type `EOF` and hit **Enter** again. Now continue with the *chmod* command from the guide above.

Comment: Alternatively you can save [this file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mamiu/6f91a9ff400784ef1d8c/raw/0061c07c5b29be221133554dfedcb7f8daa1168c/recursive_file_info.sh) and make it executable with the commands from my answer above.

Comment: Yay, that seemed to be the problem. I'm okay with the most basic unix codes - but thanks. Looking at the output now. Looks great, will modify the script a bit, maybe make it a semicolon seperated list instead but that will be easy with your excellent work - THANKS! Hmmm, getting the occational error ("invalid format character") ... anyway to suppress all errors? :-)

Comment: You can suppress all errors with `2>/dev/null` (e.g. `YOUR_COMMAND 2>/dev/null`). What you want is: `./recursive_file_info.sh 2>/dev/null > files.txt` or something like this. ;-) btw: the "invalid format character" error is printed from one of the **printf**-commands. You can try to figure out when and why the error occurs by commenting out all the printf-lines expect one and repeat that for all the printf-lines.

Comment: great, will give it a go, thanks a lot. Guess the error comes with some very ... alternative ... filenames from mac users... :-)

Comment: Yes, ``\`` and `%` could be problematic with *printf*.

Comment: Any workaround for that? Could easily imagine many files with % in the filename... :-)

Comment: Hmmm, just had a small idea to make this even more usefull. Using the GetFileInfo (http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20011018172352562) would give even more information that I could use :-) But this small executeable comes with 2,5+GB free Xcode download from Apple - and for over a year now I'm on a very limited 3G connection while waiting for fiber optics :-/ Just need the small executeable ... probably located in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/GetFileInfo ... wonder if anyone could grab it and place it somewhere for download? :-) Would be very usefull...

Comment: Got an alternative way from womewhere else: mdls -name kMDItemFSCreatorCode <filename>. Combined with the list (that I might expand myself if needed, will put it in a database table) from this site: http://whitefiles.org/b1_s/1_free_guides/fg2cd/pgs/f01_cr_typ_lst.htm ... I think I can get the info I'm after - in any case I will need som DB action with the list after I have the text output :-)

Comment: still ... if there is a workaround for the % and \ ... then I would love to hear about it :-)