# Does "$ mdls -recursive" exist?

Tags: macos, shell, ls, mdls

Can the `mdls` command be used recursively in the macOS terminal?  Is there an alternative that will get me a list of every file along with all the `mdls` info? `ls` has an option to get me some, but not nearly as many as `mdls`.

This is a followup question to [In the macOS terminal, "ls | mdls" commands are only working for the home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622643/in-the-macos-terminal-ls-mdls-commands-are-only-working-for-the-home-direct).

Comment: What do you actually want to do? There are options but you surely don’t want/need `mdls` output for every single one of 8 million files in your HOME directory and below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `globstar` shell option (Bash 4.0 or newer<sup>1</sup>), you can do something like this:

```
shopt -s globstar
mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemDateAdded **/*
```

The output will look something like

```
kMDItemDateAdded = 2018-07-10 15:33:04 +0000
kMDItemFSName    = "File1.txt"
kMDItemDateAdded = 2018-07-11 17:18:11 +0000
kMDItemFSName    = "File2.txt"
```

with the disadvantage that path information is lost.

If you have many, many files, resulting in a command line that gets too long, you can loop over the files instead:

```
for f in **/*; do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$f" "$(mdls -name kMDItemDateAdded "$f")"
done
```

with output that looks something like

```
File1.txt       kMDItemDateAdded = 2018-07-10 15:33:04 +0000
File2.txt       kMDItemDateAdded = 2018-07-11 17:18:11 +0000
```

or you could use `find`:

- GNU `find`:

  ```
  find -printf '%p\t' -exec mdls -name kMDItemDateAdded {} \;
  ```
- BSD `find`:

  ```
  find . -exec printf '%s\t' {} \; -exec mdls -name kMDItemDateAdded {} \;
  ```

---

<sup>1</sup> Which, in macOS, you'd have to install first, for example using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Comment: Note that macOS only ships with `bash` v3.2. If OP wants `bash` v4, they'll probably need **homebrew** and `brew install bash`.

Comment: @mark Right; the last `find` command should work with stock macOS, though